# Enums EF 5.0 - Database First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums, entity-framework-5, database-first

How can I make it so that my context objects uses the Enum feature in Entity Framework 5.0 if I am using Database First.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Go to the model browser and create a new enum type, then go to whatever column you wish to use it on and change its type to the enum that you just created.

Comment: In v6 (not sure about v5) you can also just right-click the column and hit "Convert to Enum" which will then take you to the enum creation dialog