# Decorating an enum on the EF object model with a Description attribute?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have defined an enum in my Entity Framework 5 model, which I'm using to define the type of a field on a table, e.g.

```
public enum PrivacyLevel : byte {
  Public = 1,
  FriendsOnly = 2,
  Private = 3,
}
```

And I have a table `Publication` that has a `tinyint` field `PrivacyLevel`, which I've mapped in the EF model to use the `PrivacyLevel` type defined above, using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11595087/7850).

But I also want to be able to display a string description for each value of the enum.  This I've done in the past for enums by decorating them with a Description attribute, e.g.

```
public enum PrivacyLevel : byte {
  [Description("Visible to everyone")]
  Public = 1,
  [Description("Only friends can view")]
  FriendsOnly = 2,
  [Description("Only I can view")]
  Private = 3,
}
```

I've got some code that converts enums to strings by checking if they have a Description attribute, and that works well.  But here, because I had to define the enum in my model, the underlying code is auto-generated, and I don't have anywhere stable to decorate them.

Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: Better to use code first then :)

Comment: @Jayantha - is it possible to switch tracks in the middle?  Everything else in the project is DB first.

Comment: Ah yes.. you can do it.

Comment: You could use a ViewModel approach and transfer PrivacyLevel to some sort of ViewModelEnum with the description attributes and use AutoMApper or manually transfer the enum value over by casing to a byte

Comment: @PatrickMagee - I don't have a clear picture of what you mean.  Perhaps you could post some sample code as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I came up with a much simpler solution: I just used an extension method to get the description of the enum.  That also made it a lot easier for localization, so I could use a Resource string.

```
public static string Description(this PrivacyLevel level) {
  switch (level) {
    case PrivacyLevel.Public:
      return Resources.PrivacyPublic;
    case PrivacyLevel.FriendsOnly:
      return Resources.PrivacyFriendsOnly;
    case PrivacyLevel.Private:
      return Resources.PrivacyPrivate;
    default:
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("level");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Not sure if this is what you are after but from what I understand i will try to be as clear as possible, since you have a concrete database first approach, you can abstract much of your Entity models to ViewModels using a Dto Approach through AutoMapper.

Using automapper profiles you can quickly setup profiles for all sorts of environments and scenarios for flexibility and adaptability

So here is this "Enum" which is causing me a problem

[image]

here is my view model for this Enum

[image]

First here is my layout

[image]

here is a simply mapping for the Account entity to a viewmodel for Account

```
public class AccountProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        // Map from Entity object to a View Model we need or use
        // AutoMapper will automatically map any names that match it's conventions, ie properties from Entity to ViewModel have exact same name properties

        Mapper.CreateMap<Account, AccountViewModel>()
              .ForMember(model => model.CurrentPrivacy, opt => opt.MapFrom(account => (PrivacyLevelViewModel)account.PrivacyLevel));

        Mapper.CreateMap<Account, EditAccountViewModel>()
            .ForMember(model => model.SelectedPrivacyLevel, opt => opt.MapFrom(account => (PrivacyLevelViewModel) account.PrivacyLevel));

        // From our View Model Changes back to our entity

        Mapper.CreateMap<EditAccountViewModel, Account>()
              .ForMember(entity => entity.Id, opt => opt.Ignore()) // We dont change id's
              .ForMember(entity => entity.PrivacyLevel, opt => opt.MapFrom(viewModel => (PrivacyLevel)viewModel.NewSelectedPrivacyLevel));

    }


}
```

Note that this does not have to apply to MVC, this can be used in WPF or other applications not tied to the Web, but since it's a good way of explaining, it's why I used MVC for this example.

When I first get a Http Get request for my profile, I grab the entity from the database
and map anything I actually need to the view

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Retrieve account from db
    var account = new Account() { Id = 1, Name = "Patrick", AboutMe = "I'm just another dude", ProfilePictureUrl = "", PrivacyLevel = PrivacyLevel.Private, Friends = new Collection<Account>() };
    // ViewModel abstracts the Entities and ensures behavour that only matters to the UI
    var accountViewModel = Mapper.Map<AccountViewModel>(account);

    return View(accountViewModel); // strongly typed view model
}
```

So my profile index view can use my enum view model

[image]

Here's the output

[image]

Now when I want to change what my privacy setting is, I can create a new EditAccountViewModel which allows me to submit a new value in a dropdown

```
public class EditAccountViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AboutMe { get; set; }
    public int NewSelectedPrivacyLevel { get; set; }
    public PrivacyLevelViewModel SelectedPrivacyLevel { get; set; }

    public SelectList PrivacyLevels
    {
        get
        {
            var items = Enum.GetValues(typeof (PrivacyLevelViewModel))
                .Cast<PrivacyLevelViewModel>()
                .Select(viewModel => new PrivacyLevelSelectItemViewModel()
                {
                    Text = viewModel.DescriptionAttr(),
                    Value = (int)viewModel,
                });

            //SelectPrivacyLevel was mapped by AutoMapper in the profile from 
            //original entity value to this viewmodel
            return new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text", (int) SelectedPrivacyLevel);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Now once I send a post of my new changed value, the interesting part is how I modify the "real" entity from the db with the updated privacy setting

On submitting the form back to my edit action you can i get the original real db entity and then merge changes if the ViewModel state is valid

[image]

AutoMapper allows you to configure how ViewModels can be mapped to Entities, 
if some properties should change, from integer entities to string values for view models,
maybe you want an enum to really be a string in the "view" and only the enum for the db,
with auto mapper it allows you to configure all these scenarious, and through convention
you dont need to configure "every single property" if your view models have the same
property names/camel case to upper case.

[image]

Lastly, before you can use these Profiles, you must load them at the application entry point, like global.asax or Main.

AutoMapper only needs to be 'configured' once to load any sort of profiles defined in the application. With some reflection you can load all Profiles in your assembly with this code:

```
public class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static void RegisterConfig()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(config => GetConfiguration(Mapper.Configuration));
    }

    private static void GetConfiguration(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        configuration.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;
        configuration.AllowNullCollections = true;

        IEnumerable<Type> profiles = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(type => typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom(type));

        foreach (var profile in profiles)
        {
            configuration.AddProfile(Activator.CreateInstance(profile) as Profile);
        }
    }
}
```

I call the configuration in my global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    AutoMapperConfig.RegisterConfig(); // AutoMapperConfig.cs
}
```

More information about how to use AutoMapper and how it can benefit you can be found 
here:

[AutoMapper Github](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)

Comment: Wow, now that's called putting effort into an answer!  +1 at least for the effort, even before I start working through it!

Comment: Hi Shaul, did this end up being what you were after? Interested to know how you got on since nobody else has answered you.

Comment: The requirement is still there, but it's been pushed down the priority list for some more urgent stuff in the meantime... so I haven't had time to try it!

Comment: I came up with a much simpler solution in the end - see my accepted answer.  Thanks for your help, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Some other idea:
Use `byte PrivacyLevelByte` in your EF classes. Create additional `partial class` for that particular model where you define property

```
PrivacyLevel PrivacyLevelEnum
{
    get { return (PrivacyLevel)PrivacyLevelByte; }
    set { PrivacyLevelByte = (byte)value;}
}
```

and define `PrivacyLevel` enum in your code and not by EF designer.
That allows you to handle any attributes but still gives you enum properties on EF models.