# is it possible in EF5 to generate an Enum with table values?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I've looked for this everywhere and the examples are of converting a column to a scalar or something.  I just want to know if following is possible:

1. Take a table e.g. Request and associated it with a table called RequestStatus, which has 2 columns: Id, Status and has 4 rows with different statuses.
2. Some how tell EF5 that RequestStatus table should actually generate an enum in c# side so I can do something like: Request.RequestStatus == RequestStatus.New
3. Every time I compile, it should update the RequestStatus Enum based on the table in the db specified in the connection string.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you need a table for this? This seems like a better fit for an enum.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this blog it is possible:

[Entity Framework 5 + Enumerations => What’s not to love?](https://web.archive.org/web/20130826185530/http://blog.develop.com/entity-framework-5-enumerations--whats-not-to-love)

Comment: it doesn't seem to map to a table called "Habitable"  It seems he's just generated HabitableEnum type and is mapping a column called Habitable of type int16 to the HabitableEnum type.  I've seen examples like this.   What I want is to map the enum to an existing table called Habitable.  This is quite a realistic scenario, but it seems Microsoft have completely missed the point if there's no way to accomplish this.

Comment: @Riz Is it not this that you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595008/enums-ef-5-0-database-first or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

As long as Entity Framework has started supporting `Enums` from version 5, you could create a [T4 Text Template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1e98c94-fd68-4d11-bc9b-c87c25b666ac) to generate `Enums` from database lookup tables and map them to the corresponding property of your entity. Here, you can find an example: 
[Entity Framework 5 and Enum support](http://amiramk.wordpress.com/2012/07/24/entity-framework-5-and-enum-support/)