# Entity Framework 6 Data Base first Enum support

Tags: c#, .net, enums, entity-framework-6

Hi guys that url http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/10/17/ef6-rtm-available.aspx saying that Enums are now supported in EF 6

> Enums, Spatial and Better Performance on .NET 4.0 - By moving the core
>   components that used to be in the .NET Framework into the EF NuGet
>   package we are now able to offer enum support, spatial data types and
>   the performance improvements from EF5 on .NET 4.0.

But how to map Tables to Enums in Data Base First approach, is it possible? I cant find any info on that.

Lets say I have a table with values:

```
Colors
1 Green
2 White
```

I want automatically build Enum based on that table, usually I've done that manually using previous versions of EF. Is EF6 Database First handle such approach?

Comment: I elaborated about using enums here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529959/map-table-column-to-enum-and-lookup-table-to-enum/19551519#19551519